# HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in when calling function from php but not from command line

Tags: php, wordpress

**Warning:** file_get_contents(https://myurl.com/generatetable.php?wh=.$atts[warehouse].&section=.$atts[section].&rnd=1199414166): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /data/6/5/58/36/5221362/user/6266536/htdocs/wp-content/themes/enfold/functions.php on line 722

I get the error when called from the following custom code in functions.php of Encode theme.

```
function WarehouseAvailability($atts)
{
   $myX = file_get_contents('https://myurl.com/generatetable.php?wh=.$atts[warehouse].&section=.$atts[section].&rnd='.mt_rand());

    return ($myX);
}
//Expected format to call the shortcode: [GenTable warehouse="" section="1"]
add_shortcode('whavailability', 'WarehouseAvailability');
```

When I call the url directly using https://myurl.com/generatetable.php?wh=Davis&section=1 it works perfectly. Also, on localhost the above code works. Does anybody have suggestions about getting this function working properly?

Comment: $myX = file_get_contents('https://cmyurl.com/generatetable.php?wh='.$atts[warehouse].'&section='.$atts[section].'&rnd='.mt_rand()); perhaps?

Comment: Single quotes will not evaluate your variables, and your concatenation attempt is all wrong. Either use double quotes (preferably with braces around your variables), or use proper concatenation.

Comment: I have been fiddling with this suggestion, but am not sure exactly how you think it should be formatted. Could you post an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$myX = file_get_contents('http://cmyurl.com/generatetable.php?wh='.$atts["warehouse"].'&section='.$atts["section"].'&rnd='.mt_rand());
```

Comment: I get: Warning: file_get_contents(https://myurl.com/generatetable.php?wh=Davis&section=3&rnd=502748920): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in /data/6/5/58/36/5221362/user/6266536/htdocs/wp-content/themes/enfold/functions.php on line 723

Comment: 400 means the the URL is unreachable, for whatever reason this URL isn't responding back I just noticed something though; can you make it http:// instead of https:// in the same example pls

Comment: @MustangGuy is your server behind a proxy?

Comment: I get the same error with http instead of https also.. just tried

Comment: I've modded my answer; the string your building to make your request is what's causing it to make an unreachable URL; the SSL was also giving an issue because the browser when I checked manually returned an error so I've modified it again

Comment: The variables your passing into this string I think is the issue; can you echo them to see you can store them in a variable? if you can I'd use those variables instead of accessing them through $atts; just trying to eliminate any bad factors :)

Comment: The modified string above also returned an error. I am 99% sure the server is not behind a proxy,

Comment: What's the idea behind the "."?

Comment: a . is a concatenation operator, allows you to concatenate (put together) a string and a variable, eg: "my name is " . $name; would return a complete string; we were trying to fix your URL by modding your request to concatenate properly; my answer was modded by aynber which makes sense; you may wanna give it a try again

Comment: The ? is part of the url and is used to pass variables to generatetable.php

Comment: Sadly I upvote and it doesn't count because I am a new poster. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**Use the curly braces({}) structure.**

You need to use double quotes around the query. This structure works only in the double quotes and inside must start with a dollar symbol like `{$atts['warehouse']}`. Otherwise, it leads to parse error.

```
function WarehouseAvailability($atts)
{
   return file_get_contents("https://myurl.com/generatetable.php?wh={$atts['warehouse']}&section={$atts['section']}&rnd=".mt_rand());

}
//Expected format to call the shortcode: [GenTable warehouse="" section="1"]
add_shortcode('whavailability', 'WarehouseAvailability');
```

Comment: That helps a ton. Thank you.